# Creating Project Summaries with New Lines in Jira Command Line Interface

Tags: command-line-interface, jira

I am trying to create a project in Jira [using the JCLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Documentation). I would like my project description to have a newline in it.

According to [this page](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/browse/JCLI-24), the following should work, but the " \n " is not converting into a new lines:

> C:\jira.bat --action createProject --project "MYPROJ" --name "My Project" --description "Line1 \n Line2" --lead "me"

Is there a way to do this short of ditching the JCLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible:

https://bobswift.atlassian.net/i#browse/JCLI-24